# build failed because of "org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: invalid code lengths set"

Tags: java, android

This error occurs whenever I try to run the app or make an apk, and I don't remember making any significant changes before this issue appeared
here are the details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: invalid block type
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$2.invoke(BuildElements.kt:133)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$2.invoke(BuildElements.kt:110)
at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt$onEach$1.invoke(_Sequences.kt:1260)
at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:149)
at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.calcNext(Sequences.kt:109)
at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:133)
at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:153)
at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toCollection(_Sequences.kt:633)
at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toMutableList(_Sequences.kt:663)
at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toList(_Sequences.kt:654)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler.transform(BuildElements.kt:140)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler.into(BuildElements.kt:115)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElementActionScheduler.into(BuildElementActionScheduler.kt:32)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doFullTaskAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:401)
```

There is a lot more to add, the error detail is over 35000 characters, but this website doesn't allow me to add all that.
I'll respond soon to any things that you might want to know

Here are the complete details of the error https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v5xZkWXORuzAUVhOl_NY2b_kBZILKrT9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What is your Gradle and AndroidStudio versions?

Comment: Looks like you have some version mismatches between your plugins. Confirm your kotlin, Gradle and Android Studio as well as build tools are all acceptable to work together as well as the packaged versions and the gradle wrapper packaged in.

Comment: @Sam I'm using plain Java in my code, not Kotlin,

Comment: @Joe My Gradle and Android Studio are all updated to the latest versions. My compile and target SDK are not though.

Comment: hi @HarshaVardhan the .kt extension is for kotlin and your error log shows kotlin, so it appears you have some kotlin dependency in there. Can you post your build.gradles so we can help. Also your gradle.wrapper

Comment: Thanks for the update, this project just started building fine, the error just appeared and disappeared for no reason, how do I learn about Gradle? It seems like I've started working on android without knowing much about Gradle first.

Comment: ahh, ok yeah sometimes a clean or invalidateCache and restart will resolve your issues. Unfortunately Gradle can get into odd states with caching at times. There are a lot of great Gradle videos on youtube you could checkout. That teaches you the tricks of coding it, but learning the idioms and weird issues you will encounter is just domain knowledge and falling in the fire enough times to know how to fix it unfortunately. There is a good community of support around it typically though.